# use the Union condition inside the Case block in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, union, case

How can we use the Union condition inside the Case block in Oracle.
Trying the below code but is not working.

```
SELECT NVL(SUM(DECR(BUDGET, 'AcKnOw%eDg3h1dD3N$4mH3RE')),0) AS budget
INTO v_budget
FROM MST_ESTIMATES
WHERE (PMT, MOTS_ACR, ENTRY_TYPE, type) IN ( (
  CASE
    WHEN (ind_est_type ='TBD'
    AND oomLockFlag    = 1)
    THEN
      (SELECT trim(getPrjData.PMT),
        trim(getPrjData.mots_acr),
        'PROJ',
        'OOM'
      FROM DUAL
      )
    UNION END )
SELECT PMT,
  MOTS_ACR,
  entry_type,
  ind_est_type AS type
FROM MST_EST_LOCKS
WHERE PMT    = trim(getPrjData.PMT)
AND MOTS_ACR = trim(getPrjData.mots_acr) (
  CASE
    WHEN ind_est_type='OOM'
    THEN
    AND OOM          = 'Y'
    WHEN ind_est_type= 'TCP1'
    THEN
    AND TCP1          = 'Y'
    WHEN ind_est_type = 'FB'
    THEN
    AND FB = 'Y'
  END ) )
AND userid IN
  (SELECT userid
  FROM mst_employee
  WHERE director = ev_director
  AND manager    = ev_manager
  )
AND firm = ev_firm;
```

Can somebody help with this.

Comment: Hi there, please define "not working". Do you get errors? Do you get unexpected output?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the CASE block with standard conditions

```
... AND  (ind_est_type='OOM' and OOM = 'Y' OR
          ind_est_type= 'TCP1' and TCP1 = 'Y' OR
          ind_est_type = 'FB' and FB = 'Y') AND ...
```

Don't forget the parentheses, because ANDs have a higher priority than ORs, in order to detach this part from the surrounding ANDs.

--

The `UNION` keyword is in a strange place. Instead of

```
...
UNION END )
SELECT PMT,
...
```

it should be

```
...
END )
UNION
SELECT PMT,
...
```

Because `END )` is the end of the CASE statement which is enclosed in braces. You want a union of the previous SELECT with the following one.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `CASE` , you can do

```
... AND CASE 
      WHEN ind_est_type='OOM' THEN OOM
      WHEN ind_est_type= 'TCP1' THEN TCP1
      WHEN ind_est_type = 'FB' THEN FB
    END = 'Y' 

   -- or 
   ... AND CASE ind_est_type 
      WHEN 'OOM' THEN OOM
      WHEN 'TCP1' THEN TCP1
      WHEN 'FB' THEN FB
    END = 'Y'
```